# How do I import sms CSV from Nokia 2370C to Iphone?

Tags: iphone, csv, sms, nokia

So my mother decided it was about time to switch over to smartphone from her old nokia 2370C and of course she asked me to transfer over her ringtones, photos, contacts including all text message both inbox, sent & archived.

I was searching around for a solution and I came across this thread ([How to import SMS backup file(CSV format) took from Android to iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782269/how-to-import-sms-backup-filecsv-format-took-from-android-to-iphone?newreg=4e7fb039b99a4c5a9dbbec497ae27220)) regarding transfering sms's via android to iphone backup using CSV file directly imported via sqlite into the backup.DB file.

That's all fine and dandy as android is very similar setup for its text messages however Nokia is very much different especially on the older model phones whereby I have 3 CSV files:

- 1 for Inbox
- 1 for Sent messages
- 1 for Archived messages

Each of which have more columns than that is required.(https://i.gyazo.com/2338704e7cffb769d5754b0b3e9acded.png).

The Inbox CSV file first 3 columns involve the type of message (SMS), followed by the the status of the message (delivered or received) then is I assume a log for the handler id. 2 blank columns followed by the date and time, another blank column then finally the message contents.

How would I using the linked thread use that information to be able to import said data from each of the 3 seperate csv files into the iphone's backup?

Answer (score 0):

You don't import it to the smartphone. You import it to the contact management software on your computer then sync with iTunes

For more details regarding software to import :https://www.aiseesoft.com/support/how-to-transfer-sms-from-android-to-iphone.html

if still need a help visit https://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/blog/import-sms-text-messages-whatsapp-iphone/ link.

else find nearest apple retail store they can help you.

Comment: Well unless you can explain how I can get an NKU file from the Nokia suite to sync up with itunes. I will consider your answer void.